# Is 4D visualization necessary?

Tags: soft-question, visualization

Is 4D visualization necessary in order to be successful at math (complex analysis for example)?

Comment: Is it necessary? Is it possible?

Comment: The chair of my last department said he never believed anyone could actually visualize 4 dimensions, although he had met people who were convinced they could. All this to say, I think the department chair was pretty successful and couldn't visualize 4D, so I don't think it's necessary, regardless of whether or not it is possible.

Comment: @fILIP: What do you mean by 4D Visualization?

Comment: @amzoti , 4-dimensional objects .

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: Perhaps you are missing the point of the question. Regards

Comment: @amzoti , please explain !

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: Obviously he is talking about 4D objects. How in the world does one propose, show, imagine and visualize this? I know people claim they can, but tell the rest of us what that is exactly. Regards

Comment: It is not necessary, but it may not be totally impossible. I have had the pleasure of attending a talk Neil Sloane, where he tried to visualize as 4D-object by showing a sequence of 2D-cross sections. His topic at the time was discretizing the (4,2)-Grassmannian, so this was fitting. Can't say I saw the light, but this was possibly due to the fact that I had not grasped the significance of the order in which the slides were shown. I guess if you used that method and built it up from shapes you have a reasonable idea, you might be able to learn...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue strongly that it isn't - I can't do it, and have never needed to. While I do study geometric problems, I do it using a lot of algebra, so I don't have to rely heavily on geometric visualization. Even 4D visualization wouldn't help, because a lot of the objects I consider have a lot more than 4 dimensions anyway.

I imagine that it could be helpful it some areas though. For example, a lot of people study 4-manifolds, which are four dimensional geometric objects (although they don't necessarily sit nicely in 4-dimensions; e.g. a hollow sphere is a 2-dimensional object, but you need 3 dimensions to draw it in). Whether some of the techniques they have for understanding them qualify as visualization is up for debate - there are certain pictures one can draw or think of, but they usually don't amount to really "seeing" the whole object.